# MongoDB Aggregate - Query to get most recent item in group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given this source data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1"), "productID" : 1, "amount" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("2"), "productID" : 2, "amount" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("3"), "productID" : 3, "amount" : 3, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4"), "productID" : 4, "amount" : 4, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5"), "productID" : 1, "amount" : 11, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6"), "productID" : 2, "amount" : 22, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7"), "productID" : 2, "amount" : 222, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("8"), "productID" : 3, "amount" : 33, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T00:00:00Z") }
```

I want to get the most recent record for each product (keyed on `productID`) and print out the full row for that record per product sorted on `productID`. So my desired output from above would be:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5"), "productID" : 1, "amount" : 11, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7"), "productID" : 2, "amount" : 222, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("8"), "productID" : 3, "amount" : 33, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-03T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4"), "productID" : 4, "amount" : 4, "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z") }
```

I'm new to Mongo and having problems, managed to get most of it but couldn't delete the other older records for each product.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) and [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operators. Note that you should sort documents before grouping:

```
db.so.aggregate([
 { $sort: {productID:-1, date: -1} },
 { 
     $group: {
         _id : "$productID",
         date: {$last: "$date" },
         amount: {$first: "$amount" },
         id : {$first: "$_id"}
     }
 },
 { $project: { _id: "$id", productId: "$_id", date: 1, amount: 1 } }
])
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "productId" : 1,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "amount" : 11
},
{
    "_id" : 7,
    "productId" : 2,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "amount" : 222
},
{
    "_id" : 8,
    "productId" : 3,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "amount" : 33
},
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "productId" : 4,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "amount" : 4
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's a big help. One thing though - I am not aware of the full document schema in advance (ie this is generic)- so I know I will have a fixed date field and a id field (date, productID) but there will be many other fields that are undefined at runtime - how could I return all the fields from an object without specifying them.